# How to retrieve data from Firestore - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to retrieve data from my `firestore` database and assign those values to a `List` in `flutter`

But the problem is even though I am able to retrieve the data, I can't assign it to a `List`

Here is how my data retrieving method:

```
Stream<List<News>> getNews(){
    return _db.collection("news") 
      .snapshots()
      .map((snapshot) => snapshot.documents.map((doc) => News.fromMap(doc.data, doc.documentID)).toList(),);
  }
```

This is where I I try to get this data from the `firestore` to a `List`

```
Widget _showSearchBar(BuildContext context) {


  List = FireStoreServiceApi().getNews(); //this produces an error, see below to see the error

  List list = [
    "Banuka",
    "Banuka",
    "Banuka",
  ];

  return GFSearchBar(
    // overlaySearchListHeight: 160.0,
    searchList: list,
    searchQueryBuilder: (query, list) {
      return list
          .where((item) => item.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    },
    overlaySearchListItemBuilder: (item) {
      return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
        child: Text(
          item,
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
        ),
      );
    },
    onItemSelected: (item) {},
  );
}
```

But this produces:

> A value of type 'Stream>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'.
>   Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List'

I don't know how to fix this and Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add type of list like below,

```
List<News> newsList = FireStoreServiceApi().getNews();
```

Comment: this produces the error `Missing selector such as '.identifier' or '[0]'.
Try adding a selector.`

Comment: Now, you can check and use `newsList`.

Comment: I think you are not getting the problem here. Just by adding the variable identifier doesn't make it work. Still gives the same error

Comment: This is the error message I am getting. `A value of type Stream> can't be assigned to a variable of type List. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to List`. I don't know why you are asking for a screenshot when it shows the same.

Comment: just change your method's return type from Stream<List<News>>  to Future<List<News>> and access following way. List<News> newsList = await FireStoreServiceApi().getNews(); Also make getNews method async.

Comment: On which line does the error is thrown? And point out that line in the question